# Mongo spring-data issue with java.util.Currency

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Getting error "No property null found on entity class java.util.Currency"

Hi I have Document Class as

```
@Document
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Course {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private Currency curr;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Currency getCurr() {
        return curr;
    }

    public void setCurr(Currency curr) {
        this.curr = curr;
    }

}
```

when in make POST request to my service with data

```
{"title":"my title","curr":"INR"}
```

i get response as

```
 {
   "id": "56b0aa010364310e094c5f30",
   "title": "my title",
   "curr": "INR"
 }
```

but when i make GET i get error

```
: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No property null found on entity class java.util.Currency to bind constructor parameter to!] with root cause
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No property null found on entity class java.util.Currency to bind constructor parameter to!
```

and response as

```
{
   "timestamp": 1454419040321,
   "status": 500,
   "error": "Internal Server Error",
   "exception": "org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException",
   "message": "No property null found on entity class java.util.Currency to bind constructor parameter to!",
   "path": "/56b0aa010364310e094c5f30"
```

}

i'm using SpringBoot 1.3.2 and Jackons version is 2.6.5

there was similar question on stackoverflow but was deleted. 
What i'm doing wrong?

Full stacktrace

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No property null found on entity class java.util.Currency to bind constructor parameter to!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:74) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:71) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:251) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:231) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1186) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:78) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1134) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:870) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:283) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:271) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:271) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:231) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:191) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:187) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:78) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2224) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1855) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:1672) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findById(MongoTemplate.java:614) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findOne(SimpleMongoRepository.java:119) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.findOne(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.wiziq.microservice.course.service.CourseService.getCourseById(CourseService.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
at com.wiziq.microservice.course.controller.CourseController.getCourseById(CourseController.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:237) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter.doFilterInternal(TraceFilter.java:148) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-1.0.0.M4.jar:1.0.0.M4]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
```

Comment: and i see that jackson had added support for java.util.currency https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.5.1

Comment: I think you just get back a String from your json not a currency object. Is it working if you change Currency to String?

Comment: Post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Full stacktrace added

Comment: I changed Currency to string and getting response as   {
  "id": "56b0b1460364f174f6204389",
  "title": "courseY_YYYY______",
  "curr": "{ \"currencyCode\" : \"INR\" , \"defaultFractionDigits\" : 2 , \"numericCode\" : 356}",
  "createdDate": 1454420294250,
  "updatedDate": 1454420294250
}

Comment: @DinkarThakur is the response now ok for you or do you need anything else?

Comment: no, i dont want to change the type to String i want to use Currency,

Comment: Why its not serialising by it self as jackon has added the support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Currency` type is currently not supported out of the box by the Spring Data MongoDB object mapping system. You can teach Spring Data MongoDB how to convert instances of that type by providing a custom implementation of a core Spring `Converter` as [described in the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-explicit-converters).

```
public class CustomMongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @Override
  public CustomConversions customConversions() {

    Converter<Currency, String> currencyToString = source -> source.toString();
    Converter<String, Currency> stringToCurrency = source -> Currency.getInstance(source);

    return new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(currencyToString, stringToCurrency));
  }
}
```

As the conversion to a `String` seems to be straight-forward, I create [a ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1372) to be resolved in the upcoming version of Spring Data MongoDB.

Comment: thanks for answer and update. there is one more question can you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220287/upsert-mongo-document-using-spring-data-mongo

Comment: Thanks for closing the issue :)

Comment: @DinkarThakur, @Oliver Gierke i'm also facing the same issue. But the suggested answer not working for me. customConversions() giving nullpointer exception at line: `new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(currencyToString, stringToCurrency));`. I donno what i'm missing here. Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else runs into @oliver-gierke's answer and get the NullPointerException like @kaluva

Spring's type resolver seems to have problems with the Lambda expression. Just change the bean definition to:

```
@Bean
public CustomConversions customConversions() {
    Converter<Currency, String> currencyToString = new Converter<Currency, String>() {
        @Override
        public String convert(Currency currency) {
            return currency.toString();
        }
    };

    Converter<String, Currency> stringToCurrency = new Converter<String, Currency>() {
        @Override
        public Currency convert(String s) {
            return Currency.getInstance(s);
        }
    };

    return new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(currencyToString, stringToCurrency));
}
```

(I'm sorry I could not add this answer as comment to Oliver's answer. Stackoverflow won't let me.)